# Queue Redis are not fired on Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-forge

I use Laravel Forge to deploy my Laravel website.

Configuration of my .env for Redis and Queues:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

I run Worker As Daemon from Laravel Forge.
No entry in laravel.log.

I use this to fire queue on Redis:

```
ProcessJob::dispatch($article);
dispatch(new ProcessJob($article));
```

The problem is queue aren't fired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with **production** in `Environment (Optional)` on Laravel Forge Queue config.

Comment: Can you explain more what the solution was?

Comment: No detailed comment/explanation on how you solved this issue

Comment: It is as he says... On Laravel Forge, when configuring a queue, there is a field that reads: "Environment (Optional)"  On that field you can set "production" or "development" or whatever environment you wish. I believe he refers to that field and that he used "production" on that field. I think this is the default value, as expressed by the field's placeholder value last time I checked..